# android activity configuration change issue

Tags: android, configuration, themes

I have an activity and in manifest i set theme Theme.Translucent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.theme"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

but now my activity does not changes orientation. Is it because of the theme? And do you know how to fix this without removing the theme?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove android:configChanges="orientation"...

Comment: I've removed it but it still does not working

Comment: Shouldn't it be android:name=".MyActivity" ?

Comment: it works the same with and without the dot.

Comment: here is the code of the manifest file and the activity

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the theme, if you add this to your activity, can you check if it is called while debugging for example?

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```